# How do I callback to my own app from Spotify API?

Tags: java, android, spotify

I'm trying to connect to Spotify via API where I need a redirect_URI on a successfull callback. However, I'm new to this and don't really know what I should do here. I tried looking for ways on how to get the URI that refers to my app but I can't find anything. How do I get the URI that links to my app?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect URL (go into your app’s settings and scroll down a bit and you’ll see an input field labeled Redirect URL. You’ll want to set this to an endpoint that your backend provides. Spotify is gonna send the user to this endpoint after the user has logged into Spotify successfully. Using a localhost URL will work if you're in dev mode.

The most apt information I found is :
https://medium.com/@stefmaxko/spotify-auth-flow-with-node-js-express-7ff13d72565a

Comment: I know all that as I followed the tutorial. My question is how I find out where I can find the redirect URI to my app

Comment: You're supposed to add the redirect URL for the app while you register your app in the dashboard.
the standard format for it being  REDIRECT_URI = "yourcustomprotocol://callback";

Comment: Yes, but what is my "yourcustomprotocol"? How do I find THIS out? What is the URI of my app?